# Select won't return any row while using node.js' pg module

Tags: javascript, node.js, select, postgresql-9.2

I am using the following piece of code to retrieve a simple row using a simple select in a `node.js` application using Postgresql:

```
client.query(sql, params, function(err, result) {
    // done(); // Releasing connection to the pool
    console.log(sql);
    var retr;
    if ( !err ) {
        console.log("Row count: " + result.rows.length.toString());
        if ( result.rows.length > 0 ) {
            retr = new UserAccount();
            parseRow(retr,result.rows[0]);
        }
    }
    callback(retr, err);
});
```

Yet, no rows are returned:

```
SELECT * FROM "MySchema"."USER_ACCOUNT" WHERE "ID" = $1;
Retrieving user account by ID = 1
No user account found!
Row count: 0
```

But, the row is there in the database, I can see it with pgAdmin III. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** There is a callback I have just added in the code.

Comment: Your log doesn't match your code. Is `params` `[1]` ?

Comment: It is because it is called from another method generating logs too. This has to do with asynchronous execution. var params = [id.toString()]; and id = 1.

Comment: Why do you pass a string ? What's the type of id in your db ?

Comment: Mostly unrelated but you don't need toString in `console.log("Row count: " + result.rows.length.toString());`

Comment: It is a bigint, I have also tried with var params = [id];, but it does not work.

Comment: You know that in node you should pass the error as the first parameter in the callback ? (yes, still not solving your real problem, but I thought it was important, for example for promisification)

Comment: I think I know what is happening. I am creating test data before I am calling the select. The inserts are created asynchronously. So, may be I am calling my select before the test data is actually created.

Comment: That could happen, yes. If you confirm please write an answer (or delete the question but don't let it pending).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was creating test data before I was calling my select, but the inserts were created asynchronously. Therefore, I was calling my select before the test data was actually created.

I implemented a solution by learning how to use [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async).